# What are these instruments?

Tags: instruments

[image: Mystery equipment]

What are these instruments? I found them together in a stainless steel box that seems designed for sterilization.

The top left instrument works like a hole punch, it can cut oval-shaped holes out of paper.

The other thing has exchangeable tips. In each tip a blade can be inserted. It is not a typical cutting blade, not sharpened on the side. It looks intended more for piercing than cutting. The handle is spring-loaded inside, allowing the blade to be pushed in. On top of the handle there is a screw which limits how far you can push the spring. I have no idea what the lever on the side of the handle is supposed to do.

I asked a few friends who are doctors or medicine students but they did not know.

Comment: I brightened the image so we can see more details. For example, you can now see that "STERIL" is stamped into the metal of the case so I think that confirms those are medical or dental tools. ("steril" translates from Danish, German, Turkish, Romanian and Swedish into the English "sterile").

Comment: Just a guess but my bet would be those are dental tools.